# How to decryption data in browser side which is encrypted on nodejs crypto lib?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, encryption

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var crypto = require('crypto');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', 'pass');
    var data = 'myMessage';
    cipher.update(data, 'utf8','hex');
    var cip = cipher.final('hex');
    console.log("Encrypted data = " + cip); // output : Encrypted data = ac56181551e250293a60b19377583462
    res.send(cip);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Above is my node js code...

Please guide me how to decrypt the return data in browser. I hate tryed the following but it was give some wrong output.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

...

http.get('/data').success(function(en){
    console.log('data = ' + en);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(en, "pass");
    data = decrypted;  // output : {"words":[1554796213,1611862464,1270695700,366896005,1827398142,-336097742,936488021,959734499],"sigBytes":-26}
});
```

Comment: This is semi-unrelated, but why are you doing this in the browser in the first place?

Comment: To expand on @mscdex question, how is the client getting your decryption key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think node's CryptoJS is not directly compatible with node's crypto module.
So the easiest way is to use CryptoJS on both sides.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var CryptoJS = require('node-cryptojs-aes').CryptoJS;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    var data = 'myMessage';
    var cip = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, "pass").toString();
    console.log("Encrypted data = " + cip); // output : Encrypted data = U2FsdGVkX1/sgjVtKYMdH9lzLm3X48+kpS2eRToWlfM=
    res.send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

And within the browser you have to to encode the decrypted object

```js
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

...

http.get('/data').success(function(en){
    console.log('data = ' + en);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(en, "pass");
    data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);
    console.log( data );  // output : myMessage
});
```

BTW:

A year ago i wrote little helpers to encode and decode between node and browser.

Server: https://github.com/mpneuried/gmail-s3-diary/blob/master/_src/lib/json-aes.coffee

Browser: https://github.com/mpneuried/gmail-s3-diary/blob/master/_src_template/js/lib/jsonaes.coffee

Comment: Above CDN is removed by Google, Please let me know another reliable CDN available.

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/crypto-js@3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js
 This is working CDN.

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS supports the same KDF function as the crypto module in node, but when the password-based encrypt call is used a random salt is generated whereas node doesn't use a salt at all. The other parameters are the same: hash is MD5 and only 1 iteration is used.

(untested) code:

```
var keySize = 256/32,
    ivSize = 128/32,
    key = CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.create({ keySize: keySize + ivSize })
            .compute(password /*, salt*/);

// Separate key and IV
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(keySize), ivSize * 4);
key.sigBytes = keySize * 4;

// decrypt
var ct = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext),
    decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ct, key, { iv: iv }),
    data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Encryption and decryption of JSON object node and html**

**Node JS**

```
var CryptoJS = require('node-cryptojs-aes').CryptoJS;

var data = {
  "glossary": {
  "title": "example glossary",
  }
}

var cip = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), "pass").toString();
console.log("Encrypted data = " + cip);
```

At browser side- 
**HTML**
**CDN -** "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/crypto-js@3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"

```
var decrypted =     CryptoJS.AES.decrypt('U2FsdGVkX1/ps2tRPpM+5elyGhaT7zpp3YL45esS57GmSLoCkhcRdJDBGPUy    uvt0tf4CY6lW2+kugXocBQkc6A==', "pass");
    data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted)
    console.log("decrypted", JSON.parse(data))
```